# POCO::PostgreSQL: How to add std::vector support to `Binder::bind`?

Tags: c++, postgresql, poco-libraries

I want to put the struct like

```
struct Person{
 int age;
 std::string name;
 std::vector<std::string> links;
};
```

into a psql table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    age          integer,
    name         text,
    links        text[]
);
```

How to add std::vector support into Poco::PostgreSQL ?

Take a look the bind method:

```
void Binder::bind(std::size_t /*pos*/, const std::vector<std::string>& /*val*/, Direction /*dir*/)
{
    throw NotImplementedException();
}
```

I know about TypeHandler for customization, but it just handles primitive types into your class, like int, std::string etc.

```
template <>
    class TypeHandler<struct CustomClass>
{}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you will store this object in PostgreSQL? Is it a table with three fields and a separate `links` table? Is it acceptable to store `links` as column-separated values or in a JSON column?

Comment: @Botje No, this is not a separate table. `links  text[]` which look like `{"link1","link2"}`.In the case of a separate table, the task becomes simple

Comment: This sounds like a deficiency in Poco, yes. I'm afraid you will have to add that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done:

```
std::vector<Person> persons;
ses << "SELECT NAME FROM NAME", into(persons), now;
```

You should read the Poco **Data User Guide** as it has a lot of info and contains your answer [here](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html#17).  It also tells you some things not to do so it is worth the read.